# Drill -up in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

What is Drill-up, Drill-down and Drill- through in SSRS. Any steps how to implement in SSRS means in report wizard.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a concept Drill-up. 
The Drill-Through in SSRS is a technique where you want to link a one report (Master Report) to other report. In a real worl reporting if some one want to see the Salary Slip (SalarySlip report) of an employee from employee list (EmployeeList) Report, Then there should be a link on employee Name where pop up of salary slip report displayed on cliking.
For further detail see the following link for drill through
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff519554.aspx

for drill down see the following link

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1329

Comment: There is a concept of drill up, although the name isn't very fitting.  Once you drill down in a report, you need a way to get back up to where you were.  That is the concept of drilling up.

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept like Drill-Up in SSRS... 
Below are the links which explain step-by-step approach for drill down and drill through..
http://www.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/139/Drill-down-in-SQL-Server-Reporting-Services-2008/

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207031.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, Drill-Up isn't really there, but if you want to be able to navigate back to a certain report (beyond just the back button) you can have links back to it but you will need to keep track of your parameters which may mean passing them down to the drill down and then back to the 'drill-up'

The other option, which I have used, is to user the 'Go to URL' option and force your drill down report to open in a new tab.  Then you can have a link to close it, or just tell the user to press the cross, and the 'parent' report is still there.

If you do use the URL option there are some globals that can help  - Globals!ReportServerUrl, Globals!ReportFolder etc.